# git clone with username and password, my password has "@" in it

Tags: git, github, git-clone

My password has @ in it and the command is failing. what's the alternative?
git clone https://username:password@github.#########XXXXX####.com

Comment: ~git clone git clone https://$EID:$SSO_PWD@github.XXXXXXXX.com

Comment: You *must* URL-encode password characters that would otherwise trigger URL stuff, i.e., replace `@` with `%40`, replace `:` with `%3a`, and replace `%` with `%25`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+escape+password

Answer (score 1):

I would use the ssh+git protocol.

The other alternative is to get a token from github and use that instead of user/pw.

putting passwords directly on the command line is a bad practice.